# How to pass variable value from one component to another component in angular 4

Tags: angular

```
export class Component{

 constructor(){}

    if (
  this.categoryId != undefined &&
  (this.serviceId == undefined || this.serviceId == 0)
) {
  if (this.locationName == undefined) {
    alert("call by category id API");
    this.postService.searchListingById(this.categoryId).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.rawdata = res.json();
      console.log(this.rawdata);
    });
    this.router.navigate(["/web/search"]);
  } else {
    alert("Call by Category Location Api");
   }
 }
}
```

> I have a value stored in **this.rawdata** and i want to pass that value to another component how to achieve it using angular 4
>
> and i have rawdata value like this

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 0: {id: 16, installerTitle: "Test71", firstName: "Test71", middleName: 
"Test71", lastName: "Test71", …}
 1: {id: 3, installerTitle: "Test19", firstName: "Test19", middleName: 
"Test19", lastName: "Test19", …}
2: {id: 3, installerTitle: "Test19", firstName: "Test19", middleName: 
"Test19", lastName: "Test19", …}
3: {id: 57, installerTitle: "Listing Title", firstName: "Pankaj", 
middleName: "Kumar", lastName: "Sharma", …}
4: {id: 58, installerTitle: "Test128", firstName: "Test128", middleName: 
"Test128", lastName: "Test128", …}
5: {id: 58, installerTitle: "Test128", firstName: "Test128", middleName: 
"Test128", lastName: "Test128", …}
```

Comment: if it is a child component, pass it as a input parameter

Comment: yes i know buti am not getting how to pass it using @Input please can u explain it

Comment: post your parent component html and child component ts

Comment: simple if you want to pass a value from one component to another component, it can be done with two ways
Model Service
@Input()